# How do I make a dice that returns a String value instead of an int?

Tags: java, dice

I need help to fix this issue in one of my methods. I need to make a die where the value is returned as a String instead of an integer value. I am having difficulties with the roll method because I don't know if there is something missing. please let me know

```
private static String[] COLOR = {"BLUE", "RED", "GREEN", "YELLOW", "ORANGE", "PINK"};
 
 public ColoredDie() {
     this.setColor(color);
     this.randomizer = new Random();
 }
 //Methods
 public String getColor() {
     return this.color;
 }//Ending bracket of method getColor
 
 private void setColor(String newColor) {
     this.color = newColor;
 }//Ending bracket of method setColor
 
 public String roll() {
    this.randomizer = new Random();
    this.setColor(randomizer.next(COLOR.length) + 1);
    this.getColor();
 }//Ending bracket of method roll
```

I tried to make the the wanted value an int, but they want it as a String.

Comment: Did you mean to `return this.getColor();` in your `roll` function?

Comment: You have a String Array - try `Color[randomizer.nextInt()]`

Comment: Have you also considered using `enum` for the colors?